# DFP - No longer working if ID is populated from database

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I want to change our DFP ad slots to be populated from the database but when I do this it does not display. It works fine if the IDs are static.

It loads the right structure up until the iframe but then the body in the iframe is empty.

I'm guessing I need to wait until the dom is ready to run the scripts or something similar?

I'm populating the IDs with Laravel blade.

Please see code below:

```
<div id="{{ $dfpData['advertisers'][0]['id'] }}" class='center-margin' style='height:728px; width:90px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: none;'>
    <script>
          googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('{{ $dfpData['advertisers'][0]['id'] }}'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any errors in the browser console? You use single quote to hold a string but you also use single quotes within the string without concatenating... `'{{ $dfpData['advertisers'][0]['id'] }}'` Maybe try swap those the opening and ending quotes for double quotes?  `"{{ $dfpData['advertisers'][0]['id'] }}"`

Comment: Thank you so much. Please add that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I appreciate that but this would be classed as a mistype/misspell which can be resolved within comments so it wouldn't really make a good useful answer. Thank you anyway :)